# How to Use VirtualEnv libraries along with system wide libraries?

Tags: python, virtualenv, graphlab

It might sound dumb, but I am having a hard time understanding how to use VirtualEnv. 
My use case is as follows:
1. My EC2 is python 2.6.9 and I need to use graphlab create which uses > 2.7
2. I installed a virtualenv and installed graphlab in it with python 2.7.5
3. Now I want to use graphlab create with my other files which are not on virtual env

Is it possible to do that? if yes how. More specifically, I want to be able to use

```
import graphlab
```

in my non virtualenv python files !!

Comment: What do you mean by `not on virtualenv`?

Comment: @flyingfoxlee, by not on virtualenv, I mean the parent env which hosts virtual env

Comment: If you need 2.7.x, install 2.7.latest. Screw crappy systems that only give you ancient software versions!

Answer (score 0):

A virtual env, as long as I know, is an enviroment binded to a specific version of python, that you could create to install into it as many libraries as you want, and be sure that noone of these libraries will be available outside of their virtualenv (system wide or other envs).

If you create a virtualenv based on Python 2.6 (let call it ENV_A), and another one based on Python 2.7 (ENV_B), there is no way to use in ENV_B a library from ENV_A.
The only way I could think to make these two enviroments to interoperate is to create a python script into ENV_A, then call it with "ENV_A\python.exe ENV_A\script.py [arguments]" using a system call from ENV_B and parse the ouput: not sure it's an option for you.